# jest mock call object is possibly undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

This is a simple test using a [mocked function](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#using-a-mock-function). But I do get an ts error for the mock call `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`. I don't see how to get rid of this error. [This is the structure](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#custom-matchers) of the call object, so I think I handle it correctly... but obviously not as expected by ts.

```
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'

const mockSetCheckbox = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())

test('should select checkbox', () => {
  // ...
  userEvent.click(checkbox)
  expect(mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0].variables.input.checkbox).toBe(true)
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to change your test to use [.toHaveBeenCalled()](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalled)

```
  test("should select checkbox", () => {
    userEvent.click(checkbox)

    expect(mockSetCheckbox).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        variables: expect.objectContaining({
          input: expect.objectContaining({
            checkbox: true,
          }),
        }),
      })
    );
  });
```

which would assert the same, but you'll get much more understandable error if the implementation changes in a way that the function isn't called.

When using `.toHaveBeenCalled()` will look like this:

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: ObjectContaining {"variables": ObjectContaining {"input": ObjectContaining {"checkbox": true}}}

    Number of calls: 0
```

[working example](https://replit.com/@StefanTeneff/ts-jest-so-67441027#test.spec.ts)

Answer (score 1):

It's saying `mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0]` is possibly `undefined`, because you're potentially doing `mockSetCheckbox.mock.undefined.variables` and you cant reference `undefined` like that.

It's trying to help you because your type for whatever `calls[0][0]` is is `undefined` and/or something else.

Simplest fix is to just assure the checker that it's not going to be `undefined` by checking first.  Shortcuts exist to do this more concisely if you don't want a buncha `if`s.

```
if(mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0]) {
   expect(mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0].variables.input.checkbox).toBe(true)
}
```

You might also want to make sure that your test fails if it **is** `undefined` by `throw`ing.  The above will silently fail since no `expect`s means 'pass'.  I prefer to do both by catching the problem and assuming all's well after looking for problems.

Something like:

```
if(mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0] === undefined) {
    throw "oh no!";
}
expect(mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0].variables.input.checkbox).toBe(true)
```

Other options include:

```
expect(mockSetCheckbox.mock.!calls[0][0].variables.checkbox).toBe(true);

// or 

expect((mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0] as Something).variables.input.checkbox).toBe(true);

// or

let val:Something = mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0];
expect(val.variables.input.checkbox).toBe(true);
```

... where `Something` is whatever type that contains that `variables` object (or `any`).

Comment: If I do `let val = mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0]`, I do get the error `Tuple type '[]' of length '0' has no element at index '0'.ts(2493)` for the last bracket.

Comment: Since this is a test case, I think the non-null assertion `!` best conveys intent. Your example isn’t quite right though, it should come after the second array access: `mockSetCheckbox.mock.calls[0][0]!.variables.checkbox`

Comment: Unfortuneatly the `!` doesn't change anything. I could do `mock.calls[0]?[0]`, but this gives me `Property 'variables' does not exist on type 'number[]'`